# mizzao:sharejs-codemirror throwing error in my meteor app

Tags: meteor, web-applications, meteor-blaze, atmosphere.js, sharejs

I just created a basic project using `meteor create CodeCollab`. Then I installed the "mizzao:sharejs-codemirror" package using `meteor add mizzao:sharejs-codemirror` command. The installation works fine without any errors. But when I start the app I get the following error - 
[image: error screenshot]

I am not able to find a solution for this error. I have not edited any file inside the project. I just created the project, installed package and hit run.

Comment: Maybe it requires you to install ShareJS manually? What does the documentation say?

Comment: @Jankapunkt The above command install both sharejs and sharejs-codemirror. Just to make sure I tried adding that separately and it showed that sharejs has already been added.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

```
meteor add edemaine:sharejs-codemirror
```